# Template Specific WordPress Sidebar

Tags: wordpress, templates, sidebar

I'm trying to get a specific sidebar to appear only on pages using a specific template, but I'm not that experienced in Wordpress theming.

The "News Sidebar" should display on pages using the `home.php` template:

```
<?php 
// If the News Sidebar is active, display on the Posts page
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-news' ) && is_page_template( 'home.php' ) ) { ?>
    <aside id="sidebar-news" class="widget-area">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-news' ); ?>
    </aside><!-- #secondary -->
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this right and you just want that specific sidebar to be shown on that specific template, you just need to include `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-news' ); ?>` on that template, that's it.  No need to do any logic because you already assigned that template to that page.

Also make sure you are naming your template so it shows up in the admin backend.  Put this at the beginning of your home.php:

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: Home
    */
?>
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but I'd prefer to keep all of the sidebar logic in the `sidebar.php` file. Sorry I didn't make that clear. That PHP snippet I posted is from the `sidebar.php` file.